# Is a halting problem oracle to itself possible if randomness exist?

Tags: computability, oracles

The usual proof that a halting problem oracle to itself don't exist is like:

> Check if itself halt, and do the opposite. Both result are conflict.

However, if it sometimes return HALT while sometimes don't, the result makes much sense.

So is an random oracle that may return "HALT" iff input program may halt, and may return "DON'T HALT" iff input program may loop forever, exist?

Comment: "may return "HALT" if input program may halt, and may return "DON'T HALT" if input program may loop forever" So, no constraints whatsoever?

Comment: OK, why not just return HALT on all inputs?

Comment: @NoahSchweber `may return "HALT" iff input program may halt, and may return "DON'T HALT" iff input program may loop forever` cover both side

Comment: OK, so how is that not just the usual halting problem?

Comment: Or is the change that our new program doesn't have to always return a value? (In which case, just never return anything on any input ever.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber It can be probablistic, sometimes return halt while other time return don't halt

Comment: "sometimes return halt while other time return don't halt" That seems to directly contradict "may return "HALT" iff input program may halt, and may return "DON'T HALT" iff input program may loop forever." I'm not sure what you're asking at this point.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Because the input program possibly sometimes halt sometimes don't